Aggregate design for a fuel tank with deliveries and fill level readings
So I've got a rather simple, mostly crud application I want to use DDD with, to learn/practice it. I wonder about aggregate design regarding a fuel tank entity. Each tank stores fill level readings (date, fill level), usually one each year, and gets several deliveries of fuel per year (date, amount, cost).
Looking at invariants, the two collections are independent from each other, and I can only see one business rule for the fill level readings: there must only be one reading for any given date.
Regarding usage patterns, the two collections are edited independently as well, because a delivery rarely happens on the same day that readings are taken. When reading a tank to display it, however, the most recent values of both collections are also needed.
What does that mean for aggregate design? I roughly see three options:

One big tank aggregate containing both collections. I can maintain the invariant, but always need to load both collections even when only editing one. (Then again, they're small enough that their size shouldn't be an issue in my example, after 20 years a tank would roughly have 60 deliveries.)
One tank aggregate, one aggregate for the tank level collection, one for the deliveries collection. The invariant can be maintained within the collection aggregate, and i only need to load the collection that actually gets modified.
One tank aggregate, but each tank level and delivery would be their won aggregate, so no collection aggregates. The invariant cannot be maintained in the model anymore, but it's a simple unique constraint so i could put that into the db layer. I only need to load and save the single values i edit, no more collections.

Given this simple albeit maybe a little vague example, do any of you with experience in DDD have a preference for an aggregate design or even a different design idea altogether?

"there must only be one reading for any given date" Consider someone realizing, right after recording a measurement, that it's wrong (whether a typo or actual instrument calibration issues). What I quoted here can be interpreted differently by different people: Are you going to disallow a new entry on a day that already has an entry? Are you allowing it but overwriting it? Subsequently: why overwrite it instead of storing both and choosing to display the latest entry for that day and effectively choose to lose the information about previous data entries?

[..] I suggest you dig deeper into whoever said there should only be one reading. They probably meant something more nuanced, e.g. they were thinking about a report that gets created at the end of the process, or they wanted the latest reading of the day to be taken (and blindly assumed that no one could ever possibly want to do a second reading on the same day for any reason), or they actively intend to disallow new input after an entry has been made (which I would very much push back against for reasons such as user error).

I'm writing this as a comment, not an answer, because it doesn't answer how you should model your domain; it only points out that the current information you've provided has ambiguities and needs to be refined in order to make an informed decision on how your domain needs to be designed. Part of this is also the consideration that your domain doesn't need to identically reflect business requirements. Your domain could track all entries, but pretend to the outside world that only the latest entries for each day exist. This is why you need to investigate what the real needs here are.

If there are typos and misreadings, you can just edit your previous entry to correct it. More than one reading per day does not make much sense because that kind of precision isn't needed, the software only operates on dates, not times. If you had 2 readings per day, how would the software know which of those to work with? Yeah, you could add time, but as i said, that just increases complexity of the data unnecessarily in my opinion.


I wonder about aggregate design regarding a fuel tank entity.

OK, so one of the things that you have to have clear in your head, is where the "book of record" lies.  If you are dealing with a collection of readings from a physical fuel tank, then the book of record is outside of your model (you can't add fuel to the tank by changing numbers in your digital representation).
Truth is what's actually in the tank; the readings from the sensors give you some approximation of that truth (which may or may not be reliable, depending on the quality of the sensors), your inputs are digital representations of those readings (hopefully without too many transcription errors), and your database is "just" a collection of cached copies of those digital representations.
In this sort of situation, your "aggregates" turn out not to be very interesting, because there's not much for them to do (other than perhaps check if some message has already been written down).
Aggregates are a lot more interesting when you have processes.  For instance, we might have a process that is responsible for deciding when to order more fuel from the vendor.  So when new information from one of the fuel tank sensors arrives, we might load stored information about the deciding, integrate the new sensor data, and update our decisions about when to schedule an order.
In very rough terms, the aggregate is interesting because it is writing down things other than just the facts it was told and what it writes down next depends (in part) on what it has written down before -- i.e. its own internal state, over which it is the sole authority.
CRUD tends to suggest that you are designing a database, so don't be in a hurry to implement a bunch of patterns that are more appropriate to a service.
For more on the book of record problem, search for discussions of modeling warehouse systems.

Thanks for your explanation and the link. I also found another answer for a related question helpful: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/355558/451610
